# No POST var in sys.stdin output using a HTML form, what can I do?

Tags: python, forms

[image: screenschot]

I'd like to replace cgi.FieldStorage() by parsing sys.stdin's output as the cgi module is deprecated, but this doesn't work, the content of 'username' doesn't show:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from string import Template
import sys

html = """
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/tools/div/py.py" method="post" name="test_form">
    <input type="text" value="" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    $result
    </form>
</body>
</html>
"""

print("Content-Type: text/html")

d   = {
    'result': '<p>result is: ' + str(sys.stdin) + '</p>'
}
src = Template(html)
print(src.substitute(d))
```

Comment: `str(sys.stdin)` is just pointing at the `stdin` textIO wrapper, did you perhaps mean something along the lines of `str(list(sys.stdin))` or `str(sys.stdin.readlines())`?

Comment: Thank you, now I get the intended result.

Comment: If you're migrating away from the cgi module I suggest you look into using Flask rather than processing `sys.stdin` yourself.

Comment: Yes, but my shared hosting only includes standard modules, adding flask manually is tedious.